# Download in iframe not working

Tags: javascript, iframe, windows-8, download, internet-explorer-10

We have an  issue in Windows 8 IE 10 with downloading.

Currently we use the following (pseudocode):

```
<form id="downloadformid" target="iframeid" action="https://url/" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="item1" value="value1"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="item2" value="value2"/>
</form>
<iframe id="iframeid" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var downloadForm = document.getElementById("downloadformid")
    if (downloadForm != null) {
      downloadForm.submit()
    }
  })
</script>
```

The problem with this is that this doesn't present the download option on Windows 8 IE 10.

Is there a reason for this, is there a fix, or a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **name** attribute to `<iframe>`

```
<iframe name="iframeid" id="iframeid" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```